# sharePoint 2010 Navigation audience after fresh migration - owners - no exact match was found

Tags: navigation, groups, audience-targeting

As a test,I just migrated my first site via db restore and add.  Some Tabs are hard coded so went to change them in naviation, but then get error with audience set to owners.. no exact match was found - can't seem to re-add it unless I search for it.

Possibly related, but we are yet to do a user profile synchronization.  Is this why?

Also, the site looks identical to the 2007 version, and I have confirmed it's on a web ap on 2010 and even clicked on the help icon and got a 2010 help page.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to take a look at this TechNet artical on [visual upgrade](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607998.aspx) which will address your UI question.

Comment: yes, this helped the site look like 2010, but still, even after importing some 17,000+ user profiles within Navigation, audience I can't just enter owners like I use to w/o getting the error: no exact match was found.